# Grub problem in uninstallation of Ubuntu in Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I uninstalled Ubuntu by following the online instructions here. First, I addressed the command prompt to fix the boot. After typing `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` , I did not reboot my PC and continued with Windows 8 launch and then removed Ubuntu from Disk Management.

On rebooting, the grub screen still remains and I have to type `exit` command and manually go to Windows Boot Manager every time.

Did this happen because I did not reboot the PC after using Command prompt?

How do I get rid of the grub now?

I tried the repair options from Windows recovery USB drive which I used, but it could not solve the boot issue.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you but my boot problem is solved. I had to install Ubuntu once again. This way I got the boot files back in the hard drive space. Then I used Boot Repair to repair my grub and then followed the uninstallation process. It is crucial while uninstalling that you first delete grub using command prompt in Windows and then delete Ubuntu from the drives. Also rebooting PC after removing grub is important.